# How can I edit Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDITED::::: Have simplified trying to figure out what the problem is. Below is what I currently have:

Inspect element(portion with .navbar):

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar {
border-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar {
position: relative;
min-height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
}
localhost/media="all"
.navbar {
border-radius: 0px;
font-size: 16px;
padding-left: 150px;
padding-right: 150px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: white;
}
```

Text editor, I have this both in my pages.css.scss & my application.css.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap';


.navbar {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

The inspect element is not picking up this change in the in padding-top at all. Also my application.css.scss says CSS at the bottom right while my pages.css.scss says Sass in the bottom right may this be the problem?

Comment: Is the problem Boostrap not being overwritten by your CSS or just the display color used by your Sublime Text editor ?

Comment: Bootstrap not being overwritten by my CSS

Comment: Ok, can you show us what's your console showing for your `.navbar` node ?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means sorry. Do you want me go to my rails console and type in '.navbar'?

Comment: I'm assuming that if Boostrap is not being overwritten then you should have a styling issue when looking in your browser right? If so, just the Chrome or Firefox debug tool, by right clicking on your .navbar

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the .navbar selection for inspect element. I've edited the question and put the information up top. Let me know if that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50953/discussion-between-rorofromfrance-and-user3408293)

Comment: Made another edit to include the striked through elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not CSS you are editing but a file with a SCSS extension . i.e. Sass. But in the bottom right corner you are editing it as a CSS file...click this to change it to Sass. (If you have installed Sass in the package manager)

The question is though do you know this is a Sass file or where you just hoping to create a CSS file?

Comment: You got it. Hmmm I am looking to edit sass I believe. How do I get it to edit sass rather than CSS?

Comment: Do you have SCSS installed in sublime text via the package manager? Also in order to compile Sass into CSS you need to be using some way of compiling it like Compass, Codekit etc..

Comment: I assume I do. I have already added a carousel using bootstrap on this project. And have edited navbar in another past project. Where can I check if I have this? Is it a gem in my gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if you want to enforce your "striked through" styles, you can use the `!important` declaration. Such as:

```
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px !important; 
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Watch out for media queries that Boostrap uses all over the place though .. especially for important components like the navbar. It will affect the style for all screen width then.